# How to disable automaticRefreshEnabled flag in react admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ automaticRefreshEnabled: state.admin.ui.automaticRefreshEnabled });`

How can we change automaticRefreshEnabled to false?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setAutomaticRefresh } from 'react-admin'
...
const dispatch = useDispatch()                         
dispatch(setAutomaticRefresh(false))
```